# ~/.bashrc is NOT sourced on ssh 'command'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, bash, bashrc

At the end of `.bashrc` I added:

```
touch /tmp/bash_noninteractive_test
```

Run:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -v -C root@example.com 'ls'
```

On the host (logged in interactively before):

```
% ls -l /tmp/bash_noninteractive_test
ls: cannot access /tmp/bash_noninteractive_test: No such file or directory
```

I thought `~./bashrc` is ALWAYS sourced in non-interactive shells, like over SSH? How do I fix that?

Systems affected:

```
% lsb_release  -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

```
 % lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)
Release:    8.11
Codename:   jessie
```

Comment: Check the INVOCATION section of the bash manual, I think that when bash is a login shell it  first  reads  and  executes  commands  from  the  file
       `/etc/profile`,  if  that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order,

Comment: Truly so. Read `man ssh`: "If a command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adding my bit to the old thread for information because the accepted answer is not the real reason for .bashrc not being read for an ssh command. I got the hint after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16547623).
The second last paragraph of the INVOCATION section in bash man page states that:

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input connected to a network connection, as when executed by
> the
> remote  shell  daemon, usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd.  If bash determines it is being run in this fashion, it reads
> and executes commands from ~/.bashrc and ~/.bashrc, if these files exist and are readable.  It will not do this if invoked  as  sh.
> The  --norc  option may be used to inhibit this behavior, and the --rcfile option may be used to force another file to be read, but
> neither rshd nor sshd generally invoke the shell with those options or allow them to be specified.

Hence although the ssh command is run as a non-interactive user, .bashrc is still loaded.

But your OS may be adding checks at the top of .bashrc similar to the following (from Ubuntu 18.04) which exits .bashrc after the first few lines for a non-interactive invocation.

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

To prevent the checks, open .bashrc and comment those lines and your ssh commands will read the whole .bashrc which is the result, I suppose, you are expecting.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Following this answer, I put the commands I wanted to be run over SSH at the top of ~/.bashrc (before `case $- in` etc) and then everything worked over SSH!!

Comment: Very insightful, resolved my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Commenting these lines didn't resolve my issue; I'll try moving this block to the bottom of `.bashrc` ..

Comment: It's important when doing `scp` and `ssh`  that the `.bashrc` file when *source* does not produce any output.  If it sends any output it screws up the scp and ssh commands and they will not work.

Comment: This can be shortened to a one-liner: `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return`

Answer (score 8):

From the INVOCATION chapter of `man bash`:

> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`, if these files exist.  This may be inhibited by using the `--norc` option.  The `--rcfile` file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of `/etc/bash.bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`.
>
> When bash is started non-interactively, to run a shell script, for example, it looks for the variable `BASH_ENV` in the environment, expands its value if it appears there, and uses the expanded value as the name of a file to read and execute.  Bash behaves as if the following command were executed:
>
> ```
>          if [ -n "$BASH_ENV" ]; then . "$BASH_ENV"; fi
> ```
>
> but the value of the PATH variable is not used to search for the filename.

So it appears that `~/.bashrc` is **never** sourced on non-interactive shells, unless `BASH_ENV` points to it.

Depending on what you wish to actually achieve, you might consider enabling `PermitUserRC` and/or `PermitUserEnvironment` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on your remote host, and then writing the desired environment variables in `~/.ssh/environment` and/or the desired commands in `~/.ssh/rc`.

**NOTE:** if you plan to use SSH X11 forwarding together with `~/.ssh/rc`, you must include a snippet of code to explicitly feed the X11 session to the `xauth -q -` command; see the example in the SSHRC chapter of `sshd(8)` man page.